# Is Prism a good product for MVVM development?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Lately I have successfully implemented a desktop application using WPF technology with MVVM achtitecture and Prism. I am very happy with how the entire, quite large project emerged, and how it is easy to maintain the entire application now. No questions about the MVVM, I am already sold on that one, but how about the Prism, would you consider that a good choice when it comes to implementing the MVVM pattern? I am quite happy with the product, but I was wondering what is your opinion on it?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: Prism is a Composite Application library, which provides features for creating composable applications, including MVVM patterns.

However, in my opinion, MVVM can be achieved using simpler frameworks like MVVMLight and Caliburn.Micro. If you don't need the extra features that Prism provides then I wouldn't use it. Extra functionality is just more code that can break, if you're not using it.

Is Prism a good product? Yes.

Comment: gotcha, I agree with you that extra complexity is not always beneficial. I don't think Prism is too complex (except things like implementing popups with INotification) , but just as you said, there could be easier ways to implement MVVM. Since you mentioned, I will consider MVVMLight for my next app. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: And one more note about the complexity. I would agree with the statement to some degree, otherwise we would stay with WindowsForms, and Asp.Net WebForms (and bad practices of app dev), and no further architectures would be used. To implement a fully scalable, extensible, maintainable, and testable application modularity is a must, hence some complexity is inevitable.

Comment: @lucas When I say complexity, I really meant functionality. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: aha, thanks for the clarification